# update linked table in Google docs Android

Tags: google-docs

If I link a table into a docs, then later change the linked table, I can click on update when I'm on the desktop.

If there a similar function on Android?

Comment: Not sure how that's related?

Comment: If I copy and paste a table from Google sheet into Google docs, it's a linked table. If I update the table in Google sheets, how can I update the linked table in Google docs?

Comment: Outside of posting a link to the table in Google Docs, I don't see a way

Comment: It's [not possible as per Google] (https://support.google.com/docs/thread/14031766?hl=en)